# Is there a way to increase the z-index of matched element by 1, without iteration?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom

I have to increase the `z-index` by 1, of all `span` with class `.page`. There can be more than 100 matched elements (*NOT more than 150 in any case*).  Right now I am iterating through each one of them and changing the `z-index` via following code.

```
  $('#mydiv span.page').each(function() {
    var zi = parseInt($(this).css('z-index')) + 1;
    $(this).css('z-index', zi);
  });
```

Is there a better way to deal with it for better performance. I am using jQuery.

Comment: did you know that you can emulate zIndex effects just by reordering elements? The last element (of a group with the same zIndex) appears topmost.  This is how jQuery UI handles draggable stacking these days.

Comment: @Alnitak You are right. But I need a kind of stack of all elements one above another for some animation effect. That is why I did not go with this solution. BTW! thanks for bringing out the point.

Comment: they'll all get stacked in DOM order (my point about the last element was just an example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to rewrite your logic not to depend on a uniform incremental z-index in the element styling. If you are only ever running this logic once, perhaps you can set up some general CSS rules that just involve toggling a class to achieve the layout you want. Assuming that is not an option, there isn't much you can do to make it more performant.

You may be able to detach the '#mydiv' element temporarily to reduce page repainting but it is hard to give more help without more info, and that can confuse other things.

```
var div = $('#mydiv');
var prev = div.prev();
div.detach();

// You can clean up your jQuery like this:
div.find('span.page').css('z-index', function(index, zIndex) {
    return parseInt(zIndex, 10) + 1;
});

div.insertAfter(prev);
```

Comment: Almost...it needs to be `function(index,value) { return parseInt(value,10) + 1; }`.  The `.css` method you're using takes the index of the selected elements first, then the value.  Good use of jQuery, though, +1.

Comment: @loganfsmyth In that case, if I use vanila javascript that would be faster I guess.

Comment: @deepak It's not the JS that is slow, jQuery or vanilla, what you are doing is just pretty ugly. I'm adding one suggestion now.

Answer (score 3):

Some tricky way is,

Create new style

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = '.cssClass { z-index: value; }';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);

document.getElementById('yourElementId').className = 'cssClass';
```

Comment: Creative thinking!  I like it.  +1.  It would be interesting to see what the performance impact of this is as compared to the other approaches.

Comment: @JaykishanMehta Here I have to add +1 to the initial value of z-index of that element.

Comment: @deepak you can store z-index's current value as global variable(on page load).And update the same depends on the situation.

Comment: But please check as @EthanBrown has said for performance impact

Answer (score 1):

In terms of performance, @Jaykishan Mehta's one is the best, then comes the for-loop.

```
for (var i = 0, spans = document.querySelectorAll('#mydiv span.page'), len = spans.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    spans[i].style.zIndex = parseInt(spans[i].style.zIndex, 10) + 1;
}
```

Using jQuery massively, i.e for each iteration etc., can slow down globally.

What I mean is that jQuery may do separate tasks quite quickly, but the sum might cause a general slowdown.

It all depends on your app/website.